# will post action work with load()?

Tags: jquery, forms, action

I'm using a load function to load a page fragment :

```
$( "#result" ).load( "site.com/ajax/test.html #container" );
```

The container has a form like this :

```
<form method=post action="send.php">
```

My question is : will the action work normal as it works on the `ajax/test.html` or not ? Should I use an iframe instead ?

Comment: Did you try to see if it worked?  It should work as long as the path to the page is the same

Comment: I tried something but I don't know I did it correct or not , I want to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form itself will work, but it will work as if the code for it were part of the web page served originally.

That is, if the action of the form is 'send.php', then the browser will interpret that as 'send.php' in the same directory as the original request. It looks like the 'test.html' page is in a directory called 'ajax', so you should make sure that 'send.php' is in not in 'ajax', but in the root (or whatever directory your initial page is in).

Comment: What if the `test.html` is on a different domain?

Comment: If the action of the form looks like `http://domain.com/test.html` then that will work the same regardless of where you load it. If you don't have `http://etc.` then the browser will take that as being the same domain.

Comment: Ok for being sure , if I load a part of `site1.com/index.html` ( which have form and an action with it [ `site1.com/send.php` ] ) into `site2.com/main.html` , the loaded form work fine? Am I correct ?

Comment: Ah, I see the problem. No, the browser will interpret the action (without an `http://` at the start) as being to the same domain as the original request (here it will load `site2.com/send.php`). If you want to avoid that you need to change the form action in `site1.com/index.html` to include the domain. If you write it as `http://site1.com/send.php` it will work. If you don't have access to do that then you could use jQuery to change it after loading, but it wouldn't be a trivial thing to do.